# insert several row in order to satisfy a constraint

Tags: postgresql, transactions, constraints

I have two table: deck(id) and card(deck,color,value)

deck have those constraints:

- `CHECK (fifty_two_cards_deck(id))`
- `PRIMARY KEY (id)`

  CREATE FUNCTION fifty_two_cards_deck(deck integer) RETURNS boolean
      LANGUAGE sql STABLE STRICT
      AS $*$ SELECT COUNT(*)=52 FROM card WHERE deck=$1 $*$;

and card have those constraints:

- `FOREIGN KEY (deck) REFERENCES deck(id)`
- `PRIMARY KEY (deck, color, value)`

How can I insert a new deck?

I tried this:

```
begin transaction;
INSERT INTO "public"."deck" ("id") VALUES (nextval('deck_id_seq'::regclass));
INSERT INTO "public"."card" ("deck", "color", "value") VALUES ('1', enum_first(null::Suit), enum_first(null::Symbol));

end transaction
```

(i had edit `fifty_two_cards_deck` to be a `one_card_deck` for testing purpose)
but I got this error:

> SQL error:
>
> ERROR:  new row for relation "deck"
>   violates check constraint
>   "fifty_two_cards_deck"
>
> In statement: begin transaction;
>   INSERT INTO "public"."deck" ("id")
>   VALUES
>   (nextval('deck_id_seq'::regclass));
>   INSERT INTO "public"."card" ("deck",
>   "color", "value") VALUES ('1',
>   enum_first(null::Suit),
>   enum_first(null::Symbol));
>
> end transaction

How can I solve this without removing the constraints?

EDIT: solution

thx to Magnus Hagander I got it working like this (after setting the foreign key deferrable):

```
begin transaction;

SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;

INSERT INTO "public"."deck-card" ("deck", "position", "color", "value") VALUES (1, 0, enum_first(null::suit), enum_first(null::Symbol));
INSERT INTO "public"."deck" ("id") VALUES (1);

end transaction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might work if you make the FOREIGN KEY with DEFERRABLE, and then set it to DEFERRED. Then you insert into the "card" table *first*, and then into "deck". Check constraints execute at the time of insert (thus, well before the entries in "card" exist), and cannot be deferred to transaction end.

But that's not actually going to work around the fact that your constraint is broken and should be removed ;) That CHECK constraint will only check rows going into "deck". But once the row has been inserted there, you will still be able to add more rows to, or delete rows from, the "card" table and the CHECK constraint will not complain - until the next time you try to modify "deck".

Comment: actually, because of the primary key on card and the fact that color and value are enum, I can't add more cards to a deck. but I can delete some. 
I'm going to look if triggers could solve that (eg, check that fifty_two_cards_deck(row.deck) return true before deleting row)

Why do you suggest to remove the constraint instead of fix this? I always thought the more (useful) constraints there is he better it is.

Comment: You may be able to fix it with a trigger, but that may well run you into concurrency issues. The reason for removing it is in the paragraph above - you're trying to use a CHECK constraint for something it's not intended to, and there are lots of pitfalls in it - just one of which is allowing DELETEs.